# Running a MongoDB in Docker using Compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a database in docker and a python script with it to store MQTT messages. This gave me the idea to use Docker Compose since it sounded logical that both were somewhat connected. The issue I'm having is that the Docker Containers do indeed run, but they do not store anything in the database.

When I run my script locally it does store messages so my hunch is that the Compose File is not correct.
Is this the correct way to compose a python file which stores message in a DB and the database itself (with a .js file for the credentials). Any feedback would be appreciated!

```
version: '3'
services:
   storing_script:
     build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on: [mongo]

mongo:
  image: mongo:latest
  environment:
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: xx
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: xx
        MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: motionDB
volumes:
- ${PWD}/mongo-data:/data/db
- ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
ports:
  - 27018:27018
restart: unless-stopped
```

The DockerFile im using to build:

```
# set base image (host OS)
FROM python:3.8-slim
# set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /code 
# copy the dependencies file to the working 
directory
COPY requirements.txt .
# install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# copy the content of the local src directory to 
the working directory
COPY src/ .
# command to run on container start
CMD [ "python", "./main.py"]
```

Comment: If you're running on Windows, I believe the docker data folder requires permissions that can't be satisfied by the Windows file system, so you have to use a docker volume. Not sure if this has been fixed in whatever version you're using, or if it relates to your problem.

Comment: @Llama running on linux, the containers do run but whenever i send an mqtt message I get no response. I have print statements everywhere but it feels as if my python file and database arent linked or connected

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be due to user permission.

What I did for my docker-compose for docker deployment, is I also mount the passwd file after creating a mongodb user

```
volumes:
    /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro
```

This worked for me as the most straight forward solution.

Comment: I mounted the mongo-init.js file which has db.createUser() in it, would i still need to do this when i dont have a passwd file?

Comment: the db.createUser() is the mongodb user permission. /etc/passwd contains the server's user file. When mongodb is ran, it runs with the user `mongodb` with the uid 1000. Since the permission is different, they may not be able to write to your local system db directory

Comment: hmm that seemed to do something, now I'm getting the error:    

mongo_1           | find: 'mongodb' is not the name of a known user.

I tweaked with the clientaddress a little because thats the only time i mention MongoDB in a string

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't understand you.. Please do not mix up docker user and mongodb user

Comment: Apologies, I meant after adding the passwd volume the containers stills run but now I get a persistent error message in the mongo container logs that read "find: 'mongodb' is not the name of a known user".

Comment: maybe got to do with your init file

Comment: in your vps, try `sudo adduser mongodb`